Proof that all natural numbers can be represented in Binary
I was just sleeping on my couch and just randomly came up with this:
Consider the following:
$$y =\frac{1}{1-x} ; \space|x| < 1$$
Multiplying both numerator and denominator with $\space(1+x)$, we get:
$$ y =\frac{1+x}{1-x^2} $$
Repeating this process $n$ more times, we get:
$$ y = \frac{(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)...(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} y =  {(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)...}$$
Using the summation formula for infinite series, we can say:
$$y = 1 + x +x^2 + x^3 + x^4 ...$$
$$\therefore (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)... \space = \space1+x+x^2+x^3...$$
From the result we can conclude that:
i) The sum of the elements any unique set of powers of 2 will give a unique natural number
Mathematically:
let $k$ be any number, then:
$$∀ \space\space k ∈  \mathbb{N}^+ \space\space∃\space\space\space S ⊂  \mathbb{N}  : $$
$$ k = \sum_{r∈S} 2^r $$
ii) Every natural number can be expressed as a sum of a unique set of powers of 2 (as the coefficient of each power of x in the series is 1).
My question is: is this proof correct? Is it already well known? What is the actual proof of proving the identity and what does 'rigor' mean truly?

Here is another proof. Let $b = b_n b_{n-1} ... b_2 b_1 b_0$ be a binary number. Consider the function $f(b) = \sum b_i 2^i = m$, where m is a natural number. $f(b)$ is bijective, so there is a one to one mapping between each binary number and each natural number (vice versa).

Yes, but then you would have to prove that $f(b)$ is onto, and you'd also have to prove it's one-one, perhaps it's not too hard to do so but it's not so easy to be certain without writing it all out.

Standard proof is the greedy algorithm.  Prove it for small $n$.  Now remove the largest power of $2$ you can from your desired $n$...the additive remainder must be less than that power, so induction works.

The division algorithm always terminates.  $n=2q_0+r_0=2(2q_1+r_1)+r_0$, etc.

Yes, such generating function-based proofs of combinatorial identities are common.  See for instance the equivalence of partitions into odd parts and partitions into distinct parts, and rather famously Euler's pentagonal number theorem.
